# How can I make fixed layout like application on bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need fixed layout design like an application (like Asana, Evernote)

How can I implement this on bootstrap 3?

[image: application design]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You create a 100% height `position:absolute` wrapper around everything, and then use `position:fixed` on the sidebar.

App example: http://bootply.com/101585

Another example w/o footer: http://www.bootstrapzero.com/bootstrap-template/app

Another with full width footer: http://bootply.com/107751

Comment: in first example, footer be corrupted when resolution changes to mobile view.

Comment: It helps set `width:100%` in .footer